# liferay display connected user in jsp

Tags: liferay

I work with liferay 5.2

in my jsp I can get the connected user  with this code :

```
<%@page import="com.nbs.fw.portal.PortalUtil"%>
String id_employe=PortalUtil.getConnectedUserID(request).toUpperCase();
```

but now I want to know the role of connected user

**Updated :**

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.service.RoleServiceUtil"%>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.model.User" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.model.Role" %>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.util.WebKeys"%>


<%
User user = ((ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY)).getUser();
List<Role> roles = (List<Role>) RoleServiceUtil.getUserRoles(user.getUserId());
for (Role role : roles) {
out.println( role.getRoleId() );
}

%>
```

but when I test I have an error :

```
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Impossible de compiler la classe pour la JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 13 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.liferay.portal.util.WebKeys resolves to a package

Une erreur s'est produite ï¿½ la ligne: 1 208 dans le fichier jsp: /jsp/_correspondencelist/html/correspondenceList.jsp
WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY cannot be resolved to a type
1205:               %>
1206:               
1207: <%
1208: User user = ((ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY)).getUser();
1209: List<Role> roles = (List<Role>) RoleServiceUtil.getUserRoles(user.getUserId());
1210: for (Role role : roles) {
1211: out.println( role.getRoleId() );


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you didn't import all classes like **WebKeys** or **ThemeDisplay**

```
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.util.WebKeys" %> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="liferay-theme" %>

<liferay-theme:defineObjects />
```

Comment: If you using old liferay version you must check that import packages are correct. [com.liferay.portal.kernel or com.liferay.portal.model]

Answer (score 0):

Change the import to com.liferay.portal.PortalUtil

```
<%
 User user = PortalUtil.getUser(request);

 List<Role> roleList = user.getRoles();
%>
```